# Nested set activity for result android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 activities. A,B and C. A calls B, B calls C, and the result of C should be received in A. Can you please suggest how to go about it?? I m killing B using finish() after it calls C. So, the result of C should go directly to A Activityonresult. Is it possible??. Please give your suggestions!

Comment: instead of killing B you should make an onActivityResult() in B and have it call setResult() passing along the result that it got from C

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't kill B, in `A` start activity `B` using `startActivityForResult` and in `B` start activity `C` using `startActivityForResult` then in B `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

where intent is the intent sent back from `C`. Now `A` will receive this intent in `A onActivityResult`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but i need to kill B. Let me explain my custom camera app, from A, i call the camera open activity in B with capture button, on click of capture in B, it goes to C with options of save and discard killing B. If its discard, B will be called from C and if its save, the bitmap is passed to A.

Comment: So, effectively, i need to close B in C before opening B again, is it possible?

Comment: onActivityResult is called before onResume, when you do as I suggested in B onActivityResult is called and then follow by onDestroy right away, so the UI of B is not shown at all.

Answer (score 2):

What if you call C from A? Something like: A calls B; instead of calling C from B, finish it and make A call C.

Unless the result of C affects B. In such case you have no choice but handling the result of C in B, and set the result of A from there if needed.